# Is there a way to scale image in one direction?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, canvas

Is there a way to scale in one direction. Normally the `scale` function scales the canvas in both the x and y direction equally, but what do I do if I want to take, say a polyline, or a group of lines, and scale them in the x direction but not in the y direction?

Best example here, http://www.giffits.de/logoplacer/lpl.php?cv=1760&mandantid=0&il=55744_1,55744_2&itemCode=55744&itemname=Carina&t=1469093996653

Comment: What are you asking? `context.scale(scaleX,scaleY)` will let you scale X independently and leave Y unscaled.

Comment: @markE If scaleY isn't defined it'll be equal to `0`, according to my browser.

Comment: @nicematt. Of course(!), I assume one would set `scaleY=1` to leave the drawing unscaled in the Y direction. So what is the questioner asking ... I don't understand them.

Comment: What are you asking? Please don't use an external link -- instead, describe your need inside your question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easier, but you can do this:

- save the y scale as value;
- update the y scale when changed;
- return the y scale in `ctx.scale(x, y)`.

If the y parameter isn't defined in `ctx.scale(x, y)`, the y scale will be set to `0`. So this is the minimum thing you can do.

---

```
var scaleY = 1;

/* change the x scale only */
ctx.scale(1, scaleY);

/* change both coordinates scale */
scaleY = 3;
ctx.scale(2, scaleY);
```

Comment: Yes I already tried, but not success.  Do you have any example demo link?

Comment: @DarshanShah Yes, here: https://jsfiddle.net/ybkq81fz/ . You should show a bit of code in your question in this case.

Comment: Nope it'll be not work like, that change both x & y direction. I want to change only one direction like example link which I shared

Comment: @DarshanShah Yes, it does that. You just need to memorize both x and y scale.